# how to convert from ITM ref to GPS ref?

Tags: c#, gps

how to convert from ITM ref (Israel new map) to  GPS ref  and from GPS ref to ITM ref?

i need any C# sample code or formula for this

for example:  `32.086156,34.769239  =  178364,665948`

or : `29.548783,34.952316  =  194997,384546`

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, if only we'd called ours IE-TM and you called yours IL-TM, there'd be less ambiguity on an international site like this.

There's a js implementation at http://code.google.com/p/js-itm/ so if the license suits your purposes, you could port that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be the *Israeli* Transverse Mercator, from the example given. There are a number of UTM to lat/long conversion tools available. [Here someone has C++ code](http://www.gpsy.com/gpsinfo/geotoutm/). I'd sugggest you ask the question on the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) site, and are prepared to write the C# code yourselves. Start with a test suite, and it shouldn't be hard - it's a straightforward mathematical formula after all.

Comment: Ah, nice one. Porting to C# should be easy.